# TypeError: undefined is not an obect(evauating 'this.statement.stateName')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
export default function App() {



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Works Fine
      </Text>

  <Hello username = "Rohith"/>
  <Hello username = "Reddy"/>
  <Hello username= {this.state.stateName} />

    </View>
  );

}

class Hello extends React.Component
{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      stateName: "nobody",
    }; 
  }


  render(props) 
  {
    return(
      <Text>
        Hi there {this.props.username}
      </Text>
    );
  }


}
```

**I have just started learning React Native. This is my first code. I face the following error. Please help me.**
I am learning how to use a constructor with state in a class. I am rendering using expo mobile application. Is this the right way to use the constructor?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function App()` so it's a functional component, you can't use `this` inside that

```
// so if you have defined state something like this
const [stateName , setStateName] = useState('')

// you can use it like this
<Hello username={stateName} />
```

OR

You can convert it to `Class based component` like this :

```
class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            stateName: "nobody",
        }; 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text> Works Fine</Text>
                <Hello username = "Rohith"/>
                <Hello username = "Reddy"/>
                <Hello username= {this.state.stateName} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

---

**WORKING CODE SNIPPET** :

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                Hi there {this.props.username}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            stateName: "Darshvi",
        }; 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Hello username = "Vivek"/>
                <Hello username = "Darshita"/>
                <Hello username= {this.state.stateName} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```